# Unable to display images [?] - Native app (PhoneGap) into Xcode

Tags: jquery, ios, cordova

I am currently using jQuery Mobile (PhoneGap) - HTML5 + CSS5 + JS and then I convert it into Xcode that supports jQuery Mobile (PhoneGap).

I test iOS simulator to see if it works finely. Indeed it works normal but I notice that some of the images shows [?]. Not sure if the problem may lies with either "Unable to display" or "the image is loading slowly". There are more than 600 images that are required to be displayed on iPad Application.

I put the images folder under "www". I even write the code like e.g.

```
<img src="Images/abc.png" width="740" height="430">
```

Do you know where the problem lies? It will be great if you could help me.

Btw, I include the jQuery script with the following code:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
```

instead of

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>.
```

Comment: Does it works fine on browser (what I mean is that you open the HTML file in the browser)?

Comment: Yes it works fine on the browser (Microsoft Firefox) - I am using Xampp but when I try to convert all of the files into Xcode because I need to use native app but some of the images does not work. Why?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a "/" at the end of your tag, and you should remove the directory reference. Try this: 
`<img src="abc.png" width="740" height="430"/>`